# Trying to construct a URL using GTFS data

Tags: gtfs

I am trying to construct a URL so that it shows the time of the next Train at my particular stop.

I am using the information on this site(below) to gather this info and construct the URL.

https://github.com/ineptech/mirror
I tried following the documentation here at Step 8 (this one uses portland data but i am trying to use the Long island data in NYC).

I am having trouble navigating myself around the data finding the location for Island Park, NY, 11558.

I would appreciate any help dealing with GTFS.

EDIT: Once i got the API key, i was able to navigate here http://web.mta.info/developers/developer-data-terms.html#data but unable to construct a link for Island Park, NY.

The GTFS Data for the location i found

{"stop":{"stop_id":"104","stop_name":"Island Park","stop_lat":"40.60129","stop_lon":"-73.65474"}}

Under routes.txt, this is the relevant info

"6","","Long Beach","2","FF6319","FFFFFF"

Under stops.txt, this is the relevant info

"104","Island Park","40.60129","-73.65474"

Comment: This appears to be primarily a question about the MTA Long Island commuter rail real-time data feed, rather than GTFS (although they appear to use GTFS-rt as their feed format). The URL format is presumably completely different from TriMet in Portland, which is why the example you found wouldn't work. I don't have an API key so I can't check, but the documentation for the feed seems to be here: https://mnorth.prod.acquia-sites.com/wse/LIRR/gtfsrt/realtime/[PutAPIKeyHere]/json.

Comment: Nothing happens when i type in my Key in the URL, the key is free to sign up for btw